# Fetch MySql data into <select>

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get values from mysql into `<select>` tag.
I have used while loop & getting data from 2 different tables.
I have tried the given code but not able to get the data.
Please Help!

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name  

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from dummy");

$uresult=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name from user where role='Support'"); 
$uname=array();
while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($uresult))
{
$uname[]=$rows['name'];
}
echo "<table border='1' width='100%' >
<tr><th colspan='7' ><h2 align='center'>Details</h2></th></tr>
<tr bgcolor='grey'>
<th width='10%' class='text-center'>Emp No.</th>
<th width='15%' class='text-center'>Name</th>
<th width='30%' class='text-center'>Task</th>
<th width='20%' class='text-center'>Assigned To</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['emp_no']. "</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['emp_name']. "</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['task'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center'> <select name='select1'> <?php while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($uresult)) { ?><option><?php echo $rows['name'];?> </option><?php } ?> </select> </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: you are trying to echo an <?php syntax. Very poor coding. echo "<td align='center'> <select name='select1'> <?php while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($uresult)) { ?><option><?php echo $rows['name'];?> </option><?php } ?> </select> </td>";

Comment: why are you trying to double fetch it? you already got it inside your container

Comment: There are so many red flags in this code i don't know where to start. Please read PHP manual a little more. I wanted to write a detailed answer, but then  I realized it won't help you, because you are not yet familiar with basic language syntax, and i can't teach you all of it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is with below line
you have php code inside the string

```
echo "<td align='center'> <select name='select1'> <?php while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($uresult)) { ?><option><?php echo $rows['name'];?> </option><?php } ?> </select> </td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to fetch it over again. You've already done that here:

```
$uname = array();
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($uresult)) {
    $uname[] = $rows['name'];
}
```

So inside the other while block, just use that names that already gathered:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['emp_no']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['emp_name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['task'] . "</td>";
        echo "
        <td align='center'>
            <select name='select1'>
        ";
        foreach($uname as $names) {
            echo '<option>' . $names . '</option>';
        }
        echo "
            </select>
        </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Or just create an HTML string of `<options>` with the `$uname`, then just `echo` it inside the `while`:

```
$uname = '';
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($uresult)) {
    $uname .= '<option>' . $rows['name'] . '</option>';
}
```

Then on the `while` block:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['emp_no']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['emp_name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['task'] . "</td>";
        echo "
        <td align='center'>
            <select name='select1'>
        ";

        echo $uname; // collection of HTML string options

        echo "
            </select>
        </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: this is what i meant by pre populating select. But why make that foreach run inside while, run it outside once, in while() you can have a constant string.

Comment: @MuhammedM. yup i already made the edit

Comment: Thank you. And I am strong opponent of echo's inside while, it slows down performance, decreases readability. I prefer assigning values to a dummy variable inside loop and outputing it after the loop ($out.="..")

Comment: Thank You i got the required result.I know i am beginner & learning it

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, `embedding` php in html

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td align='center'><?php echo $row['emp_no'] ?></td>
    <td align='center'><?php echo $row['emp_name'] ?></td>
    <td align='center'><?php echo $row['task'] ?></td>
    <td align='center'> <select name='select1'> 
    <?php while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($uresult)) { ?>
    <option><?php echo $rows['name'];?> </option><?php } ?> 
    </select> </td>
    </tr>";
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: $uresult=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name from user where role='Support'");   --->  if select is going to populate the same result, why put it inside loop? store it outside and pass it as a variable to this <tr> while. Very bad code indeed, by the author, i didn't mean you, since you are just trying to provide a quick fix.

Comment: Thats upto the questnr to put it wherever he wants, but one thing sure is he wants to loop SELECT * from dummy statement in the table rows and SELECT name from user where role='Support' in the select option